# C# XNA touch panel - Surface Pro touchscreen not recognized

Tags: c#, windows-8, xna, touch, multi-touch

I used some tutorials on the internet that taught how to use touch input in XNA for windows computers with a touch screen. However, I'm using a Surface Pro and the XNA studio doesn't even recognize it as a touch screen. I used a test by printing the status of TouchPanel IsConnected and it was false. The maximum touch capability returned 0 (I think surface has a multitouch of 10).

Is anyone familiar with this? I was trying to do some simple tasks like, receiving multiple finger clicks on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

XNA 4.0 doesn't support touch on any device other than Windows Phone 7. See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/09/09/touch-input-on-windows-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) for full details.

That linked blog post provides some alternative methods for receiving touch input (basically: use the Windows APIs).